# JBoss 7.1, BlazeDS 4 and RestEasy integration

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jboss7.x, blazeds

I have a simple web app running BlazeDS 4 running on JBoss AS 7.1. I'm trying to add resteasy but there seems to be issues connecting when creating a rest call. I think that BlazeDS is somehow blocking rest from being used. When I create a separate project with rest it works as expected, but when added to my existing project the following error is shown in the logs.

(with blazeds)

13:48:12,459 ERROR [org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Received invalid request for endpoint path '/rest/hello'.

This is what appears when the call is successful  (w/o blazeds)

13:52:00,914 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class rest.JaxRsActivator

For reference here is the example I followed
[RestEasy Jax-RS in Jboss 7.1 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223968/resteasy-jax-rs-in-jboss-7-1-doesnt-work/16228079?noredirect=1#comment23246042_16228079)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found that by creating a mvc with spring I am able to create rest calls. 
I followed the testdrive tutorial that comes prepackaged when downloading spring.
Here is the documentation

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html