# RESTeasy Jboss 7.1.1 Final ContainerRequestFilter @Provider not called

Tags: maven, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm trying to implement a security measure in my webserver using the ContainerRequestFilter provided by JAX-RS 2.0 and supported by RESTeasy 3.0.5Final. I'm using JBoss 7.1.1 as my platform.

I added the following class to my project:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class ServiceInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext arg0) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("request filter");

}

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext arg0, ContainerResponseContext arg1) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("response filter");

}

}
```

However, neither of the two methods is called when I try to access my RESTful API, such as:

```
@Path("/users")
@RequestScoped
public class UserRESTService {

@Inject
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GET
@DenyAll
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<User> getAll() {
    return userRepository.getAll();
}
}
```

I tried adding the @Provider in the web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>com.package.my.rest.ServiceInterceptor</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. 
    and/or its affiliates, and individual contributors by the @authors tag. See 
    the copyright.txt in the distribution for a full listing of individual contributors. 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not 
    use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy 
    of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tellyo.uam</groupId>
    <artifactId>uam</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>uam</name>
    <description>A starter Java EE 6 webapp project for use on JBoss AS 7 / EAP 6, generated from the jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype</description>

    <url>http://jboss.org/jbossas</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
            message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
        <version.jboss.maven.plugin>7.4.Final</version.jboss.maven.plugin>

        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
            tested stacks. -->
        <version.jboss.bom>1.0.7.Final</version.jboss.bom>
        <!-- Alternatively, comment out the above line, and un-comment the line 
            below to use version 1.0.4.Final-redhat-4 which is a release certified to 
            work with JBoss EAP 6. It requires you have access to the JBoss EAP 6 maven 
            repository. -->
        <!-- <version.jboss.bom>1.0.4.Final-redhat-4</version.jboss.bom>> -->

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.10</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill 
                of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
                of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
                of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools stack (you can 
                read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with some extras tools 
                for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate 
                stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with extras 
                from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
            of them are provided by JBoss AS 7 -->

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
            as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <!-- JAXB support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- multipart/form-data and multipart/mixed support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

        <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
            typesafe criteria queries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
            annotations are incorrectly used. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
        <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
            JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
            given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The JBoss AS plugin deploys your war to a local JBoss AS container -->
            <!-- To use, run: mvn package jboss-as:deploy -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
                just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
                tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in your 
                JBoss AS instance -->
            <!-- This profile will start a new JBoss AS instance, and execute the 
                test, shutting it down when done -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-managed -->
            <id>arq-jbossas-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in a remote 
                JBoss AS instance -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote -->
            <id>arq-jbossas-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

I removed the following entry from it:

```
<!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Because I understand that the JAX-RS API is provided in the RESTeasy packages and what I need is JAX-RS 2.0, which includes the ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter classes.

What else am I missing? Why aren't the filters called?

Comment: I noticed the following message in the logfile:

WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2

Does this mean that I'm using JAX-RS 1.1 and the filters are not included there? How can I upgrade to 2.0 if that is the case?

Answer (score 5):

As I suspected, JBoss was confused and was still partially using the old RESTeasy version. The solution is to upgrade RESTeasy in JBoss, according to RESTeasy documentation:

3.1. Upgrading Resteasy Within JBoss AS 7

Resteasy is bundled with JBoss AS 7. You will likely have the need to upgrade Resteasy in AS7. The Resteasy distribution comes with a zip file called resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.5.Final.zip. Unzip this file while with the modules/ directory of the JBoss AS7 distribution. This will overwrite some of the existing files there.

**UPDATE:** It may sound silly but I encountered a similar problem 6 months later trying to deploy a web application on Wildfly 8. This time, I forgot to add the SecurityInterceptor to the JaxRsActivator class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
    /* class body intentionally left blank */
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(RESTTest.class, SecurityInterceptor.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and the solution was simple.
Besides upgrading the modules using the file in RESTEasy distribution (which didn't solve for me at first), I actually removed all resteasy parameters from web.xml and added an Application annotated class as in the solution to this other question: [RestEasy Jax-RS in Jboss 7.1 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223968/resteasy-jax-rs-in-jboss-7-1-doesnt-work)

Comment: You're right. At this moment, my web.xml file is empty as far as RESTeasy is concerned. I'm also using the Application annotation.